# How can end My Youtube live stream API in c#?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, live-streaming

How to stop my livestream in YouTube while completed my live telecast using c#

How to stop the livestream Using c# Code, can you please give some suggestion

```
string[] scopes = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload" };

                var creadentails = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        new ClientSecrets
                        {
                            ClientId = YTPublishSettings.PublisherClientId,
                            ClientSecret = YTPublishSettings.PublisherClientSecret,
                        },
                        scopes, "user", default).Result;

                if (creadentails.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
                    creadentails.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Wait();

                var secrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = YTPublishSettings.PublisherClientId,
                    ClientSecret = YTPublishSettings.PublisherClientSecret,
                };

                var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = creadentails.Token.RefreshToken };
                var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer { ClientSecrets = secrets }),
                "user", token);
                var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                    ApplicationName = "**************",

                });
                var broadcast = new LiveStream
                {
                    Cdn = new CdnSettings
                    {
                        FrameRate = "35fps",
                        IngestionType = "rtmp",
                        Resolution = "720p"
                    },
                    Snippet = new LiveStreamSnippet
                    {
                        Description = Description,
                        Title = Title,
                    },

                };
                var request = service.LiveStreams.Delete(YTPublishSettings.PublisherId);
                var response = request.Execute();
                return new YouTubeStreamDeleteStatus()
                {
                    success = "Deleted",
                };
```

How can end My YouTube live stream API in c#?